# Assigning multiple classes to initialized object

Tags: php

I'm currently reading a book on design patterns and in the book he uses an example like this:

```
<?php
//Client.php
/*Age groups:
18-29: Group 1
30-39: Group 2
40-49: Group 3
50+ : Group 4
*/
function __autoload($class_name)
{
    include $class_name . '.php';
}

class Client
{
    //$hotDate is component instance
    private $hotDate;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->hotDate=new Female();
        $this->hotDate->setAge("Age Group 4");
        echo $this->hotDate->getAge();
        $this->hotDate=$this->wrapComponent($this->hotDate);
        echo $this->hotDate->getFeature();
    }

    private function wrapComponent(IComponent $component)
    {
        $component=new ProgramLang($component);
        $component->setFeature("php");
        $component=new Hardware($component);
        $component->setFeature("lin");
        $component=new Food($component);
        $component->setFeature("veg");
        return $component;
    }
}

$worker=new Client();
?>
```

My question is the wrapComponent function.  How is possible for a class variable to be initialized multiple times without losing the previous contents?  In my mind, the only thing that would return would be component with the Food class, since it was the last to be initialized.  Sorry if this is obvious question, but I couldn't find anything online and I have never seen this done before.

Comment: The methods `ProgramLang`, `Hardware` and `Food` might return an object with previous data + new data inside. So the result can be cumulative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing to remember is objects are passed by reference so when you are reassigning values to a reference it only will destroy the object is there are no other references to it.

The new operation resolves before the assignment in each of these cases so a reference is maintained to the component throughout the chain, the reference that exists within each of the newly created objects.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an implementation of the Decorator Pattern.
Find [here](http://www.phpdesignpatterns.com/design-patterns/pattern-decorator/) an other exemple that might help you to understand this pattern.